# Is there a script to Python for Click to toggle selectable?

Tags: python, arcpy, python-addin, python-toolbox

I cannot write a script using ArcPy (Click to toggle selectable).

To make a layer unavailable for sampling!

I just need to create a tool to automate several processes, one of them is the ability to automatically turn off the sample multiple layers on the map! To do this manually! It turns out I have a database with all the layers, I need to when starting a new mxd, clicking on a script or a tool to fully customize my card as I need))

[image]

This script does not work, maybe someone else will?

`import arcpy
names = "[R_01_001]"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
for layer in layers:
    if layer.name in names:
        unselectable_objs=True
        print unselectable_objs
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()`

This script does not work

`import bpyunselectable_objs = []
for obj in bpy.data.objects: 
if obj.hide_select == true: unselectable_objs.append(obj) 
obj.hide_select = falseprint(unselectable_objs)`

---

Comment: You seem to be trying to morph your question into a new one.  If you have another question then please ask it as a new one.  If you do then please explain where you obtained the code that you preface with "This script does not work" because it seems to be trying to reference objects from somewhere other than ArcPy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you describe will, I think, need you to code using ArcObjects instead of ArcPy (or arcpy.mapping) because you appear to be wanting to customize the ArcMap application.

From [Who is arcpy.mapping for? Why was it built?](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Introduction_to_arcpy_mapping/00s300000032000000/):

> Arcpy.mapping is not a replacement for ArcObjects but rather an
>   alternative for the different scenarios it supports. ArcObjects is
>   still necessary for finer-grain development and application
>   customization, whereas arcpy.mapping is intended for automating the
>   contents of existing map documents and layer files.

Comment: I just need to create a tool to automate several processes, one of them is the ability to automatically turn off the sample multiple layers on the map! To do this manually! It turns out I have a database with all the layers, I need to when starting a new mxd, clicking on a script or a tool to fully customize my card as I need))

Comment: Comments are not designed for presenting code snippets.  If you have a follow up question then the way to ask it is as a new question.  That will give you access to the code formatting button **`{}`**.

Comment: Selectable is not exposed to arcpy. I think it would be worthy of an improvement request as that's something that would be fairly commonly controlled. The interface you'll need is IFeatureLayer.Selectable http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0012000004wm000000 which isn't too hard to control but there's a *big* learning curve just to get there.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson It would be nice to be able to control Selectability from ArcPy but I think it might take a lot for that to happen so late in the development cycle of ArcMap.  If an ArcGIS Idea gets written up by anybody then I think they should target ArcGIS Pro instead.

Comment: Agreed @PolyGeo, the ArcGis Pro product line is still fledgling and doesn't have mountains of existing scripts. However, historically, implementations of python have been more flexible... remember gp = arcgisscripting.create()? I don't think a fundamental change like gp => arcpy is going to happen again soon though.